# Slice image wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

In WPF I have an Image, Is there a way to apply for example these coordinates (native to the image):
0,10 20,0 20,20
to selectively display only the triangle that is formed by those coordinates.

Based on H.B.'s good advice I can opacity mask but i cannot place the map properly, nor crop to fit the opacity mask.
Example below was supposed to be over Illinois

```
 <Image Source="http://www.digital-topo-maps.com/county-map/united-states-map.gif" Stretch="None">
    <Image.Clip>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="444.806216983824,129.344961240310"  IsClosed="True" IsFilled="True">
                <LineSegment Point="445.976759660097,145.147286821705"/>
                <LineSegment Point="431.344976206682,170.313953488372"/>
                <LineSegment Point="447.732573674507,188.457364341085"/>
                <LineSegment Point="458.852729099102,213.038759689923"/>
                <LineSegment Point="469.387613185561,214.209302325581"/>
                <LineSegment Point="481.093039948293,191.383720930233"/>
                <LineSegment Point="479.337225933884,143.391472868217"/>
                <LineSegment Point="477.581411919474,132.271317829457"/>
                <LineSegment Point="444.806216983824,129.344961240310"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create this triangle as the [`OpacityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacitymask.aspx) or [`Clip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx) of your image.

e.g.

```
<Image.Clip>
    <PathGeometry>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="0,10">
            <LineSegment Point="20,0" />
            <LineSegment Point="20,20" />
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
</Image.Clip>
```

```xml
<Image.OpacityMask>
    <VisualBrush Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Path Fill="Black">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="0,10" IsClosed="True" IsFilled="True">
                            <LineSegment Point="20,0" />
                            <LineSegment Point="20,20" />
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Image.OpacityMask>
```

---

You could crop the Image space using the margin:

```
<Image.Margin>
    <Binding Path="Clip.Bounds" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
        <Binding.Converter>
            <vc:BoundsToMarginConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
    </Binding>
</Image.Margin>
```

The converter:

```
public class BoundsToMarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Rect input = (Rect)value;
        return new Thickness()
        {
            Left = -input.Left,
            Right = -input.Right,
            Top = -input.Top,
            Bottom = -input.Bottom,
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This is hardly a nice solution but it seems to work...

Comment: Opacity mask does not seem to support <Polygon> is there something I'm missing

Comment: You can create a path though, see the example i added.

Comment: Thats awesome, just one more question, Is there a way to make it only take up the path bounds. ie 20x20 instead of the full image size? Thanks

Comment: Hmm, good question, i thought [`Clip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx) (which is the more appropriate property anyway) might do that automatically but it doesn't look like it, there might be possible to do something via binding, might need another container...

Comment: Image.Clip, does seem to clip it, unfortunately leaving white

Comment: I tested a few things and found one option using the `Margin`, see my updated answer... (Unless you set the alignments to something else than `Center` or `Stretch` the placement might be a bit weird though)